# C# Send string and video stream at the same time over Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, send

I am using Sockets in C# to send string over network. I am sending strings without any problems but I am trying to stream video in byte Array with string at the same time. In other words, I would like to send two byte Arrays as one message.

Why I need it? I need it to stream to particular user and the way I do it is by specifying in string username who should receive the video and second byte Array would be accepted by that user and by nobody else.

I send string by using this code:

```
public static void Send(string text) //Send String to the Server
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(text);
            Main.AppControls.ClientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this to make one sending function not separate but as one.

```
public static void Send(string text) //Send String to the Server
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(text, byteVideoStream); <---- THIS IS WHAT I NEED
            Main.AppControls.ClientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Obviously if I stream only one byte Array with video stream and receive it in server side, I won't be able to specify person who would receive it. But if with string it has second byte array I can navigate to user who would receive it.

UPDATED
I have established protocol between Sender and Receiver
When server receives a string byte array it will read first word and if it contains for example "Connect" then server pass this to all clients:

```
if (_function== "Connect") // Client Sending Connection
   {
   foreach (Socket _connectedUsers in Server.clientSockets) //Send message back to everyone but accepts only this user.
           {
             byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Connected" + "-" + "UserName"); //Passing Message to Other Clients from where specific client will pick it up
             Socket socket = (Socket)_connectedUsers;
             socket.Send(data);
           }

    }
```

Comment: An open socket is already bound to a specific user.   Why would you need to state that user information specifically in your stream?  Is your server acting as an intermediary between two users?

Comment: Intuitively, I feel like you need to be using something like Protocol Buffers for this.

Comment: When I use Send(String) it goes to server and from server it is broadcasting to all connected sockets.  When I use string, I can specify username in string from server and client will accept string only if it contains his username. But not when I send Video Array. It's just a bytes and no strings to specify username. Does it make sense?

Comment: Well, sure, but if the server has software on it that only accepts strings and not video streams...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I was going to mention protocol buffers but wasn't sure from memory whether it can handle a open-ended data like a video stream. I've only used it for serializing objects in the past. Is it able to handle that scenario?

Comment: @EricJ. The video stream would have to be packetized, and then buffered at the receiving end for playback.  So there's probably some missing parts.

Comment: I have updated my post to show what I do in server. This is how I navigate string to particular user. I just trying to do String and byte[] together so that I can stream Video not to everyone but to user I am sending to.

Answer (score 0):

You can send whatever raw bytes you want to across your socket.

It's up to the receiving end to understand what data you are sending and interpret it appropriately.

The problem you'll need to solve is establishing a protocol between sender and receiver to understand where the string ends and the video stream begins. You might do this, for example, by terminating every string with a UTF32 character that won't be part of an ordinary message or by sending a fixed-length string.

> If I stream only one byte Array with video stream and receive it in server side, I won't be able to specify person who would receive it

I'm not sure what you mean by this. The open socket is already connected to a specific device on the other end. If your receiving code somehow routes/proxies the video stream to another device, you could for example use the string portion to specify a final recipient of the video stream and have your receiver open a new socket to the final recipient and copy the video portion of your stream to that new socket.

Comment: I have edited my Post. in Updated section you can see what I do in Server. This is how I navigate where to send string. Problem is that I can't do it String and another Byte[] to navigate Video to same user that received string.